# complex analysis question

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is an analytic function in an open set containing the closed unit disk and if $k$ is a positive integer, then there exists a $z_0$ with $|z_0|=1$ and $\left|\frac{1}{z_0^k}-f(z_0)\right|\geq 1$.

Here is what I have: Suppose thios was not true.  Then for each $z$ with $|z|=1$, we have $\left|\frac{1}{z^k}-f(z)\right|<1$.  From this we get $|1+-z^kf(z)|<|z|^k=1$ on the boundary of the closed unit disk.  So by Rouche's theorem, $g(z)=1$ and $-z^kf(z)$ have the same numbers of zeroes in the unit disk.  Clearly $-z^kf(z)$ has a zero at 0.  So 1 must equal zero somewhere and we have a contradiction.

Is this right?  If not, am I on the right track?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks fine to me. One minor point you haven't stated explicitly is that both functions in Rouche's Theorem must be non-zero on the boundary of the disk. Luckily, the hypothesis precludes this from happening.

Comment: @acoustician Is there ever a need to state that point? Rouche's theorem says that if $|f|>|g|$ on the boundary, then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros in the domain. The inequality implies that neither $f$ nor $f+g$ vanish on the boundary.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how does the inequality imply that ***f+g*** does not vanish on the boundary?

Comment: @acoustician: $|f+g|\geq |f|-|g|$.